# How to compile Kotlin domain module with client module with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have the following project structure:
 - `parent`
 - - `client` (written in Kotlin but compiled to JS)
 - - `server` (written in Kotlin)
 - - `model` (written in Kotlin)
`client` module has a dependency on `model`. So when I compile `client` to JS it also should compile `model` with it. For now I have the following Gradle configurations which are not doing the desired thing:

**project/parent.gradle**

```
group 'com.vchernogorov.tycher'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile project(":model")
    compile project(":client")
    compile project(":server")
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

**project/settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'parent'
include ':model'
include ':server'
include ':client'
```

**project/model/build.gradle**

```
group 'com.vchernogorov.tycher'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

**project/client/build.gradle**

```
group 'com.vchernogorov.tycher'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
    compile project(":model")
}

build.doLast {
    configurations.compile.each { File file ->
        copy {
            includeEmptyDirs = false

            from zipTree(file.absolutePath)
            into "${projectDir}/web"
            include { fileTreeElement ->
                def path = fileTreeElement.path
                path.endsWith(".js") && (path.startsWith("META-INF/resources/") || !path.startsWith("META-INF/"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `gradle build` command on `client` I get this message:

```
:model:compileKotlin
Using kotlin incremental compilation
:model:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:model:copyMainKotlinClasses
:model:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:model:classes UP-TO-DATE
:model:jar
:client:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:client:compileKotlin2Js
e: project/client/src/main/kotlin/HelloWorld.kt: (30, 19): Unresolved reference: Position
e: project/client/src/main/kotlin/HelloWorld.kt: (50, 5): Unresolved reference: Test
e: project/client/src/main/kotlin/SocketHandler.kt: (10, 36): Unresolved reference: User
:client:compileKotlin2Js FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':client:compileKotlin2Js'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.891 secs
```

These 3 classes are defined in `model`.
So what should I do to successfully compile `client` and not changing the code?

Comment: You compile `client` to `js` and `model` to `java`. And now you wan't to use classes from the `model` which are compiled to `.class`-files within your `client` code which is compiled to `.js`? Is this right? So you basically want to use the code from `model` in `client` is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed the following architecture for my application:
I have `client`,`server` and `model` modules but also I have a separate source directory with DTOs called `dto` (not module btw). Here's the dependency hierarchy for the build:

- `client` depends on `dto`
- `server` depends on `model`
- `model` depends on `dto`

With such hierarchy model can still use `stdlib` functionality and `server` will share all DTOs with `client` module. Meanwhile `dto` module will use the `stdlib` if it's compiled as `module` dependency and `stdlib-js` if it's compiled as `client` dependency, so it important to remember which classes you are able to use there.

In order to achieve this, you need to add

```
sourceSets.main.kotlin.srcDirs += '../dto/src/main/kotlin
```

config to both `client` and `model` build.gradle files. For Gradle Kotlin DSL:

```
the<JavaPluginConvention>().sourceSets {
    "main" {
        java {
            srcDirs("../dto/src/main/kotlin")
        }
    }
}
```